# Add nested assets directory to PBXResourcesBuildPhase by folder reference

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcodeproj

I use [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) gem to add some files in `post_install` hook. How can I add nested folder of assets into `PBXResourcesBuildPhase`? This is how it looks when I add folder by drag & drop it into Xcode and selecting `Create folder references` option:

**Project tree aka PBXProj:**

[image: Image description]

**Copy Bundle Resources aka PBXResourcesBuildPhase:**
[image: Image description]

**Folders need to be added by reference**. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be quite simple:

```
project = Xcodeproj::Project.open('MyApp.xcodeproj')
target = project.targets.find { |target| target.to_s == 'MyTarget' }
parent_group = project.groups.select { |group| group.name == 'Parent' }

assets_path = 'path/to/assets'
assets_ref = parent_group.new_reference(assets_path, :group)
target.add_resources([assets_ref])
```